# How can I set the Sales Team employee on an estimate in NetSuite with a script?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm working in NetSuite and I have a custom field on an estimate for the outside sales rep. When the record is submitted, I want the employee field under the Sales Team subtab to be set to the same value as the custom outside sales rep field. However, when I try to do this with a user event script, nothing happens. I am using the after submit function. Any suggestions? Here is what my code looks like:

```
function afterSubmit(scriptContext){

    var record = scriptContext.newRecord;


    var outsideSalesRep = record.getValue({
        fieldId: 'custbody_bs_salesrep_outside'
    });


    record.setSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'salesteam',
        fieldId: 'employee',
        line: 0,
        value: outsideSalesRep
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this in beforesubmit, not after (unless you're explicitly reloading the record and saving it again in your script). The record has already been written to the database in aftersubmit & the object returned by scriptContext.newRecord is essentialy readonly, that's why it's discarding the changes.

Comment: You can also do it as aftersubmit. There are scenarios that you need to save the record first before updating it again.

Comment: True, but in this case I didn't want to reload the record, I just wanted it to update on save. Thanks for the tip!